# Reference Request for Cycles with many chords

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I have come across the following paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.09157.pdf

The question is how many edges in an n-vertex graph will force the existence of a cycle with as many chords
as it has vertices. The abstract of the paper quotes a result of Chen, Erdos and Staton (Theorem 3 of the paper [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82473256.pdf)) as a baseline they are improving, but the problem is actually a bit different. The result of Chen, et al. cares about the existence of $n$ chords where $n$ is the number of vertices of the whole graph, while the new paper is comparing the number of chords to the length of the cycle.

I am looking for references for the case where one compares the number of chords and the length of the cycle. Especially, I wonder if the proof can be significantly easier if the condition $\Omega(n\log^8n)$ is lossen to $\Omega(n^{1+\epsilon})$.